# Ansible: How to select an import-playbook?

Tags: ansible

my master.yaml imports two playbooks.

- import_playbook: test1.yaml
- import_playbook: test2.yaml

I would like to only run import test1.yaml if tags "firstImport" is specified. eg:

```
$ ansible-playbook master.yaml --tags "firstImport"
```

May be, some kind of master.yaml coding to exit after test1 has been executed?, like:

```yaml
---

- import_playbook: test1.yaml 

- meta: end_play
  tags: "firstImport" 

- import_playbook: test2.yaml
```

or a conditional import test1.yaml with when tags is specified?

```yaml
---

- import_playbook: test1.yaml 
  when: 
  tags: "firstImport" 

- import_playbook: test2.yaml
```

How can I code this import_playbook selection? Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to

> only run import test1.yaml (playbook) if tags "firstImport" is specified

[Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance) apply ONLY to the tasks. [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#importing-playbooks) is not a task.

An option would be to import playbooks [conditionally](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals). See an example below.

```
> cat test12.yml
- import_playbook: test1.yml
  when: test1_tag | default(False) | bool
- import_playbook: test2.yml
  when: test2_tag | default(False) | bool

> cat test1.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="test1 running."

> cat test2.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="test2 running."

> ansible-playbook -i 'localhost,' -e 'test1_tag=True' test12.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "test1 running."
```

Because [values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) variables test1_tag and test2_tag shall be explicitly cast boolean.

Comment: Good point Vladimir! May be the workaround would be to pass the tags into a variable, so I can set a conditional import_playbook?

Comment: Yes, conditionals will do. I've added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Ansible 2.5](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.5.rst#minor-changes-4) a better way exists to use tags with import_playbook without resorting to vars. I was able to have tags work as I wanted to by using when conditional and the new ansible_run_tags and ansible_skip_tags lists provided by Ansible:

```
- import_playbook: test1.yml
  when:
    - "'firstImport' in ansible_run_tags"
    - "'firstImport' not in ansible_skip_tags'"
  tags: firstImport
```

In my case I wanted to also run my tag when no tags were specified, so added **or 'all' in ansible_run_tags** to get that.

```
- import_playbook: test1.yml
  when:
    - "'firstImport' in ansible_run_tags or 'all' in ansible_run_tags"
    - "'firstImport' not in ansible_skip_tags'"
  tags: firstImport
```